# To get different values from mysql

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-7

I have a problem with render different value from mysql. I just use laravel-7^ and I would like to render the column name and not the column id.

I have three tables: Day, agent, user.

In day table, there are this date:

| ID | agent_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

In agent table, there are this date:

| ID | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |

In user table, there are this date:

| ID | name |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | Marco |

Now, I get the information because i use join method:

```
$days = DB::table('days')
       ->join('users', 'days.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
       ->join('users', 'days.agent_id', '=', 'users.id')
       ->select('days.id', 'users.name')
       ->get();
```

The first problem is that i can't use two times "users" table with join. The second problem is that i can't get the name of agent because days.agent_id = agents.id and agents.user_id = users.id.

Someone may help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building SQL queries, you need to provide unique aliases to tables (and columns), but your current query does not match the relationships suggested by your sample tables (`days` does not have `user_id`). I think it should be:

```php
$days = DB::table('days')
       ->join('agents', 'days.agent_id', '=', 'agents.id')
       ->join('users', 'agents.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
       ->select('days.id', 'users.name')
       ->get();
```

Comment: Yes! I just resolve it. I have to use another query. Thanks!